# Java validate a map has required list of keys and that their values are not empty nested list or map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8

In Java how do i ensure that a map has required list of keys and that their values are not empty nested list or map

e.g. good map

```
Good Map example:

{"key1": ["a1", "a2"],
 "key2": {"x": "y"}}


{"key1": {"x": "y"},
 "key2": ["a1", "a2"]}
```

I want to make sure that the above map has required keys of `key1` and `key2` with the values being non-empty list/map

e.g. bad map

```
Good Map example:

{"key2": {"x": "y"}}


{"key1": {},
 "key2": []}

{"key1": "badValue", "key2": "badValue"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have found it:

Simple function:

```
public static boolean isObjectNullOrEmpty( final Object c ) {
  if (c == null) {
    return true;
  }

   if (c instanceof Collection<?>) {
     Collection<?> col = (Collection<?>)c;
     return col.isEmpty();
  }
   if (c instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
     Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>)c;
     return map.isEmpty();
  }
   return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
  // check if a map contains required keys and those required keys have values as Collection which are not empty
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
  Map<String, Object> nestedMap1 = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put("state", "UP");
  }};
  map.put("key1", nestedMap1);
  map.put("key2", new HashMap<>());

  List<String> requiredKeys = Arrays.asList("key1");
  System.out.println(map.get("key1"));
  Boolean mapContainsEmptyStuff = requiredKeys.stream().anyMatch(
      key -> isObjectNullOrEmpty(map.get(key))
      );
  assert mapContainsEmptyStuff == false;
  System.out.println(String.format("mapContainsEmptyStuff: '%s': %s", map, mapContainsEmptyStuff));

  requiredKeys = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2");
  mapContainsEmptyStuff = requiredKeys.stream().anyMatch(
      key -> isObjectNullOrEmpty(map.get(key))
      );
  assert mapContainsEmptyStuff == true;
  System.out.println(String.format("mapContainsEmptyStuff: '%s': %s", map, mapContainsEmptyStuff));

  requiredKeys = Arrays.asList("key1");
  HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("key1", "badValue");
  }};
  mapContainsEmptyStuff = requiredKeys.stream().anyMatch(
      key -> isObjectNullOrEmpty(map.get(key))
      );
  assert mapContainsEmptyStuff == true;
  System.out.println(String.format("mapContainsEmptyStuff: '%s': %s", map, mapContainsEmptyStuff));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would model this as a method that returns `true` when all the keys are present and valid, and `false` otherwise. I would represent the required keys as a `Collection<String>` so that I could easily iterate over them.

```
Collection<String> keys = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2");
```

Then I would loop over this and check that each key is present and valid:

```
public static boolean isValidMap(Map<String, Object> map, Collection<String> keys) {
    for (String key : keys) {
        Object value = map.get(key);

        if (isInvalid(value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The last piece is determining if a given object is invalid:

```
public static boolean isInvalid(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return true;
    }

    if (o instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection) o).isEmpty();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Of course, you can tweak the `isInvalid()` method for whatever behavior you require.